# Saving texts from textField without clicking or pressing the save button in java swing

Tags: java, swing

How can I save the text inputted in textField without clicking or pressing save button in java swing.

Comment: When should the text be saved? On what condition?

Comment: You can use onFocusLost.

Comment: @AndrewThompson when inserted

Comment: @Bart onFocusLost text is saved when I have to click the save button

Comment: Use the [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) Luke!

Comment: @Akeedify `when inserted` - how do you know when the user has finished typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `DocumentFilter` and add it to your `JTextField` using the following: `((AbstractDocument) textbox.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);` to add it. Here is an example a **MCVE**:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class Example extends JFrame {

    JTextField textbox = new JTextField(" ", 20);

    public Example() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        DocumentFilter filter = new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
                AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
                System.out.println("Inserted!");
            }

            public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
                throws BadLocationException {
                super.remove(fb, offset, length);
                System.out.println("removed!");
            }

            public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
                AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
                System.out.println("replaced!");
            }
        };

        ((AbstractDocument) textbox.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);
        panel.add(textbox);
        add(panel);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }
}
```